# How can I solve undefined method `[]' on Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get an `if` statement for users who put incorrect data.

Here's my code:

````````
class Breweries::CLI

  def start 
    puts "Hello!"
    puts "---------------------------"
    puts "Please enter your location:"
    input = gets.strip.downcase
    @data = Breweries::API.get_breweries(input)
    @objects = Breweries::HoppyCode.all 
    if input.length < 1 
      puts "Sorry!!" 
      puts "```````"
      start
    else 
      display_info 
    end
  end 

  def display_info 
    puts "You'll love the following spots!"
    puts "********************************"
    @objects.each.with_index(1) {|brewery, index| puts "#{index}. #{brewery.name}"}  
    puts  "Please make a selection by index number for more information:"
    input = gets.strip.downcase
    if(input.to_i > 0)
      @brewery = @objects[input.to_i - 1]
      puts "name: #{@brewery.name}"
      puts "street: #{@brewery.street}"
      puts "city: #{@brewery.city}"
      puts "phone: #{@brewery.phone}"
      puts "website_url: #{@brewery.website_url}"
      display_info
    elsif (input == "quit")
      quit 
    elsif (input == "menu")
      start
    end
  end

  def quit 
    puts "Goodbye. Drink responsibly and enjoy." 
  end   

end
````````

When I put something that would generate an error, it returns the following:

```
Please enter your location: nvifpejvf80ejvip
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 2: from bin/breweriesCLI:6:in `<main>'
 1: from /home/munificent-format-5297/Development/breweries/lib/breweries/cli.rb:8:in `start' /home/munificent-format-5297/Development/breweries/lib/breweries/api.rb:6:in `get_breweries': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How can I solve the undefined method '[]' error? Here's the API code in case that's necessary.

```
class Breweries::API

  def self.get_breweries(input)
    @breweries_hash = HTTParty.get("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_city=#{input}")
    breweries_obj = {
      name: @breweries_hash[1]["name"],
      street: @breweries_hash[3]["street"],
      city: @breweries_hash[4]["city"],
      phone: @breweries_hash[10]["phone"],
      website_url: @breweries_hash[11]["website_url"]
    }
    Breweries::HoppyCode.new(breweries_obj)
  end 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the input is invalid, the call to

```rb
@breweries_hash = HTTParty.get("...")
```

returns not the object you expect (I’d suggest it returns an empty hash.) That makes it impossible to get to details in the following lines. Depending on how are you to handle it, you might decide to e. g. early return from this function, or `raise`, or do something else.

To approach this, start with debugging the issue, like this:

```rb
@breweries_hash = HTTParty.get("...")
puts @breweries_hash.inspect
...
```

That way you’ll see what gets returned and get the ideas of how to handle it.

If I am right, and what is returned is an empty hash, you might want to early return from this function.

```rb
@breweries_hash = HTTParty.get("...")
return if @breweries_hash.empty?
...
```

Comment: You were right, it returned an empty hash and that  `return if @breweries_hash.empty?` solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Identifying the Problem

There are lots of ways to solve for the nil problem, but at a quick glance it seems like part of the problem here is that you're somehow expecting *input* to return a valid Hash object from your API call, but an empty String or an instance of FalseClass may not do that. Consider the following:

```
input = gets.strip.downcase # <RETURN> here gets an empty string
input                       #=> ""
input.to_i > 0              #=> false
```

Then consider that some downstream of Breweries::API.get_breweries is expecting to operate on a Hash object instead if an instance of NilClass. In this case, that looks like `@breweries_hash[1]["name"]` and other operations on *@breweries_hash*.

### Some Options

Without knowing more about your code, I don't want to be prescriptive here. But in general, you can do one or more of the following:

- Coerce arguments into the expected class in the method call, the method signature, or the method body. For example, for Array objects:

  ```
  # coerce a String to an Array, raising an exception if it can't
  input = ""
  Array(input)
  #=> [""]

  # coerce some Array to a Hash
  array = [:name, "foo", :street, "bar"]
  Array(array.each_slice 2).to_h
  #=> {:name=>"foo", :street=>"bar"}
  ```
- Explicitly check that you have an Hash object:

  ```
  fail "@breweries is not a Hash" unless @breweries.is_a? Hash
  ```
- Raise an exception rather than return `0` if *input* isn't actually a valid Integer representation in the first place:

  ```
  input = Integer(gets.strip.downcase)
  ```
- Check if your Hash or Array object responds to the relevant method calls, and raise a more helpful exception message:

  ```
  raise sprintf("@brewery: %s", @brewery.class) unless @brewery.respond_to? :[]
  ```

There are other things you might do as well. Broadly speaking, you need to adjust your code to check the return value of your call to ensure it's not nil, then branch/raise/rescue appropriately depending on whether or not you ever *expect* nils as a valid return value from Breweries::API.get_breweries.

### A Note on Using Exceptions for Non-Exceptional Circumstances

As a rule of thumb, you should only raise exceptions for truly unexpected circumstances, or when the program should halt because some condition can't (or shouldn't) be handled within the program during runtime. Which is best in your particular use case is really a design decision, and outside the scope of the original question. However, you might want to read Avdi Grimm's *Exceptional Ruby* for a deeper explanation of when exceptions might better than branching or handlers (or vice versa), but the choice in your code is a little left of center of the problem you're actually dealing with right now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and explanation. However, I'm new to this (literally my first project) and though I tried, seems like I'm making random combinations than truly understanding the issue. I keep getting the same error. 
Any other suggestion would be welcome. BTW, thanks for the book recommendation. I'll take a look at it.